# When/How to set UIImageView contentMode (UIImageView setContentMode not working)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, contentmode

I cannot figure out why the `UIImages` in my `UIImageViews` are not properly resizing to the size of the `UIImageView`. Can anyone shed some light on the problem in my code? The follow is the relevant code from my `SidewalkPlusSuperCell`, which is a subclassed `UICollectionViewCell`. I am trying to construct a `UICollectionViewCell` from code that displays a `UIImage` (a flyer), but cannot get the flyer `UIImage` to fit/resize to the size of the `UIImageView`. I know that I have to set the `contentMode`, but no matter where I seem to set the `contentMode`, the images remain unsized.

```
//
//  SidewalkPlusSuperCell.m
//

#import "SidewalkPlusSuperCell.h"
#import "Masonry.h"

@interface SidewalkPlusSuperCell()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL showInformation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *flyerImageView;
@end

@implementation SidewalkPlusSuperCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _showInformation = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)updateConstraints
{
    if (_showInformation) {
        UIEdgeInsets imagePlusTextPadding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
        [_flyerImageView mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.equalTo(self.superview.mas_top).with.offset(imagePlusTextPadding.top);
            make.leading.equalTo(self.superview.mas_leading).with.offset(imagePlusTextPadding.left);
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.superview.mas_bottom).with.offset(imagePlusTextPadding.bottom);
        }];

    } else {
        UIEdgeInsets onlyImagePadding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        [_flyerImageView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.edges.equalTo(self.superview).with.insets(onlyImagePadding);
        }];
    }

    [super updateConstraints];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (_showInformation) {

    } else {
        _flyerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [_flyerImageView setFrame:rect];
        [_flyerImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [_flyerImageView setImage:self.flyerImage]; //self.flyerImage is a public property that is set by the UICollectionViewController
        [self addSubview:_flyerImageView];

        UIEdgeInsets onlyImagePadding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        [_flyerImageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.edges.equalTo(self.superview).with.insets(onlyImagePadding);
        }];
        [self updateConstraints];
    }
}


@end
```

When I run the code, I get the following: [image: Caption]

The cells are supposed to be different sizes (sized based on aspect of the original photo), but the photos are supposed to resize to fit the cells. Any thought as to why the `UIImages` are not resizing despite me setting the `UIViewContentMode`?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting the parent view's clipToBounds?

if image view is in self.view then do

```
 self.view.clipToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I tried adding self.clipsToBounds = YES, but that did not change anything. (I had already added this to the `UICollectionViewController` cellForItemAtIndexPath method. I even tried removing the cell.clipsToBounds in the `UICollectionViewController` and only putting it in the `UICollectionViewCell` body, but that did not change anything.)

Comment: can you set imageView's clipToBounds to YES as well?

Comment: Calling [_flyerImageView setClipsToBounds:YES] unfortunately does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will solve your issue but as a recommendation:

You shouldn't call [super updateConstraints]; after any code. As a best practice you call super methods first then you type your code as apple documentation indicates to add code before the super invocation can cause unexpected behaviour.

```
- (void)updateConstraints
{
  [super updateConstraints];

    if (_showInformation) {
        UIEdgeInsets imagePlusTextPadding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
        [_flyerImageView mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.equalTo(self.superview.mas_top).with.offset(imagePlusTextPadding.top);
            make.leading.equalTo(self.superview.mas_leading).with.offset(imagePlusTextPadding.left);
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.superview.mas_bottom).with.offset(imagePlusTextPadding.bottom);
        }];

    } else {
        UIEdgeInsets onlyImagePadding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        [_flyerImageView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.edges.equalTo(self.superview).with.insets(onlyImagePadding);
        }];
    }


}
```

Comment: The ( very smart ) authors of objc.io state to put your update constraints code before calling super.  

`The place to add local constraints is updateConstraints. Make sure to invoke [super updateConstraints] in your implementation after you’ve added whatever constraints you need to lay out the subviews.`
http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html